# How do I determine the output voltage in this diode circuit schematic?

Tags: diodes

What is the sketch of the output voltage (Vo) when the input voltage (Vi) is 5sin(t) V? Assume these are ideal diodes. I am confused because when Vi is 0V, the only 1V is dropped across the resistor due to the current source and there is 14V left.

[image: Schematic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The +15V is a red herring and completely irrelevant since the current source delivers 1mA of current, no matter what it is connected to.  So you have to add up your voltages from the *only* potentials relevant to this circuit, which are the cathodes of the diodes: the diode with the lower cathode potential will be conducting and the resistor will add a fixed voltage due to it being driven with a fixed current.

Comment: What he said - and note, for ideal diodes, D2 conducts when bottom of 1K tries to rise above 0V and so ...